# Including a reledpar/reledmac file

Tags: reledmac, reledpar

I have a main file and some included files. The first included file has a structure similar to the example given in the `reledmac`/`reledpar` documentation which name is “4-reledpar_column_mix_with_not_column” and the second file has a structure similar to the given example in the same documentation which name is “3-reledpar_mwe”. Including first file only, the result is ok and same including second file only, but including both files there is an error and it seems that first file is influencing second file, it seems a numbering problem. In the given MWE there are two identical included files but the typesetting result in page 4 (first page of the second included file) is not correct. Any help?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[series={},
    nocritical,
    noend,
    noeledsec,
    nofamiliar,
    noledgroup]
    {reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}
\include{sub/main_1}
\include{sub/main_2}
\end{document}
```

first included file

MAIN 1

```
\begin{abstract}
This file provides two minimal examples of typesetting parallel texts with reledmac plus reledpar. 

The first minimal example is parallel typesetting in columns, the second one is parallel typesetting in pages.
\end{abstract}


\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pages} 
\Pages
```

Second included file is identical.

Comment: Please minimize your code and try to get everything needed in your MWE. Inserting your sample file two times results in no error and I don't want to search 7 pages of output for some error. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi the bug can happen only after 7 pages of output.

Comment: @PaoloMascetti : the bug is not related to sub file, but to alternance of Pages / Columns. try for example https://gist.github.com/maieul/2e5079d72f133894b1c5 : there is not sub file. I am looking for this bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said, the bug was not linked to including file, but to alternate \Pages \Columns.

Try this file for example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia,fontspec,xunicode,etex}
\usepackage{libertineotf}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[series={},
    nocritical,
    noend,
    noeledsec,
    nofamiliar,
    noledgroup]
    {reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}


\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pages} 
\Pages



\begin{pairs}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pairs} 
\Columns

\begin{pages}
    \begin{Leftside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph. Left side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.  Other left side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Leftside}
    \begin{Rightside}
        \beginnumbering
            \pstart
                Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph. Right side paragraph.
            \pend
            \pstart
                Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph. Other right side paragraph.
            \pend
        \endnumbering
    \end{Rightside}

\end{pages} 
\Pages

\end{document}
```

The version 2.3.0 of reledpar, juste uploaded on CTAN, solve it.

Comment: No, I don't need it quickly; in the meanwhile I have a lot of things to write. Thank you for your support.

Comment: so juste wait the next release (I hope middle september). And don't forget to validate the answer when you will have done the test

Comment: I have juste send it in ctan.